# Cmake error at find packages to finish the build

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to build easyhttp - https://github.com/sony/easyhttpcpp/wiki/Installing-EasyHttp#build-easyhttp
and after Cmakeing , it doesn't find packages to finish the build

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoConfig.cmake:29 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PocoNetSSL" with
  any of the following names:

    PocoNetSSLConfig.cmake
    poconetssl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PocoNetSSL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "PocoNetSSL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "PocoNetSSL" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/d/Linux/easyhttpcpp/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Did poco get installed correctly after following the instructions in the page you linked?

Comment: Yes it's correctly installed

Comment: Where is it installed?

Comment: Usually the solution to this error is to do what CMake is telling you.

Comment: The Debian / Ubuntu **poco** packages will match easyhttp : `apt install libpoco-dev` ...... Example, Ubuntu 20.04 → No cmake errors. $ make : No errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POCO Core library doesn't include the PocoNetSSL components. So they need to be installed additionally.

With vcpkg run to list the different poco components available:

```
./vcpgk search poco
```

You should get an output similar to this:

```
poco                     1.11.0           Modern, powerful open source C++ class libraries for building network and ...
poco[mariadb]                             MariaDB support for POCO
poco[mysql]                               Mysql support for POCO
poco[netssl]                              NetSSL support for POCO
poco[pdf]                                 Haru support for POCO
poco[postgresql]                          PostgreSQL support for POCO
poco[sqlite3]                             Sqlite3 support for POCO
```

To insatll poco[netssl] with vcpkg run:

```
./vcpgk install poco[netssl] --recurse
```

When using vcpkg don't forget to integrate the installed libraries to make them  available:

```
./vcpkg integrate install
```

Check out https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/ for more information on how to use vcpkg with cmake.